# What does "straight hustle" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I was reading [Scam City: The unlicensed 'forex trader' who lost £3.8 million](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bbcthree/article/1bee6bdc-9cc6-4415-84fc-6536ec31d46c). Excerpt:

> It didn't sound like natural territory for a bio-med student - but on his Instagram profile he explained his philosophy with the words: "No rich parents. No excuses. **Straight hustle**."

What does "straight hustle" mean?

"Straight" could mean "honest", and "hustle" could mean "scam" (in American English). This does not make sense. An "honest scam"?!

Comment: "Straight" can mean "honest", but that's not its only meaning.  [Other dictionary definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/straight) include *direct* and *free from extraneous matter* and *not deviating from an indicated pattern*.  Do some of those seem like they make more sense?

Comment: @stangdon No, I think the problem is in my interpretation of "hustle".

Comment: The comment is ironic. My answer is correct. Yes, it means he has to work. But it's gangster slang. It's a joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hustle" in this sense means "hard work". He's saying he didn't get where he is by inheritance, but by pure effort.

Answer (score 0):

'Straight hustle' in this case is a slang way of saying "entirely focused on the work I am doing". 'Hustle' generally implies not just work, but also a continuous and varied stream of work. Adding 'straight' to 'hustle' is a hyperbolic way of essentially saying "I am working all the time; I'm doing everything within my power to get what I want." I hope that clears it up for you!

Comment: It does not imply all the time, or continuous. It means actually: plain hard work.

Answer (score -5):

A straight hustle, means an **unquestionable hustle**. A **real** hustle.

Also: straight, as say, opposed to twisted or convoluted.

We say: **straight** shooter, for a person who is honest and above board.

Since a hustle by definition is a swindle, a straight hustle is just **funny**.

Similar to: He was an honest criminal. Not devious. It is ironic.

Merriam Webster: First meaning
Definition of hustler
: a person who hustles: such as
a: one who obtains money by fraud or deceit : SCAMMER, SWINDLER
A financial hustler who orchestrated the theft of $6.5 million from investors …
— Shayna Jacobs and Alec Tabak

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. Why would this person say that his personal philosophy involves swindling?

Comment: It is ironic. As I said. Shall I repeat that? It comes from the slang for something else. To hustle. The problem is bending to the reality of how Americans actually speak. I might even say that what I do is a straight hustle, ironically.

Comment: @Flux People around here need to bone up on their American slang.